# How to link to a database page

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I have a page displaying the titles of articles in my database. They are links and when clicked go to a separate page that I want to display the title and content according to the id. The link looks like this:

```
        echo '<h2><a href="../../pages/content_page/contents_page.php?id='.$review_id.'">'.$title.'</a></h2>';
```

and the page displaying them has this code:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $review_id = $row['review_id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $review = $row['review'];
} ?>
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1><br /><br />

<p><?php echo $review; ?></p>
```

But when I click a link, the url shows the correct id number but the title and content showing is the same for every link that I click. How do I get them to change for each separate id? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Full code here:

```
<?php

include '../../mysql_server/connect_to_mysql.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `review_id`, `title`, `review` FROM `reviews`");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Posts!</title>

<body>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $review_id = $row['review_id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $review = $row['review'];
} ?>
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1><br /><br />

<p><?php echo $review; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need that while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `review` FROM `yourtable` WHERE `review_id` = '$id'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
//$review_id = $row['review_id']; **You will not need this because you already have it in the URL
$title = $row['title'];
$review = $row['review'];
?>

<h1><?=$title?></h1><br /><br />
<p><?=$review?></p>
```

**EDIT:** Change:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `review_id`, `title`, `review` FROM `reviews`");
```

To:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `review` FROM `reviews` WHERE `review_id` = '".$_GET['id']."'");
```

Also... You will want to do some filtering on `$_GET['id']` like:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,9}$/', $_GET['id'])
```

(Assuming your IDs are numbers)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching *all* rows. You need a `WHERE` clause.

```
$review_id = intval($_GET['review_id']);
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT title, review FROM reviews
                         WHERE review_id = $review_id");
if (!$resource) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error());
}
# etc..
```

Comment: DO: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT title,...`

Comment: I did that just didn't put the whole code in the question. Sorry, should have been more clear. Any other solutions?

Comment: @user1371489: My answer showed you where you went wrong even before you posted your code. I've edited it slightly now to better match your code, but my original answer pretty much exactly showed you the line you needed to fix and how to fix it.